# Unsuccessful connection to sample Employee.gdb from FireDac Explorer

Tags: delphi, firedac, interbase

I open the `FireDAC Explorer` in `Delphi Community`, select `EMPLOYEE` in the left pane, change the default definitions in the right pane by choosing `Local Protocol` and `350 Port`, and select `Test...` in the Connection menu. Then I get the following error message

> Access violation at address 00774F7E in module 'FDExplrer.exe'. Read of address 00000000.

I also get error messages when trying to connect from anyone of the Interbase sample programs.

I can open `Employee.gdb` from the `IBConsole`. No problem with `Firebird`.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Do you have both the Interbase and Firebird server services on your machine and, if so, do you get the same result if only the Interbase service is running?

Comment: Yes, I have both services running. But I installed Firebird after I saw that I couldn't connect to Interbase samples.

Comment: Well, installing Firebird just adds an unwelcome complication, imo.  If I were you, I would completely uninstall Firebird and persist with trying to connect via the Interbase server.  Refer to the Interbase Operations Guide (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/InterBase/XE7/en/Operations_Guide, but available as a .Pdf) and use the cmd-line utilities to check that your config is correct.  Then try to connect using DBExpress rather than FireDAC.  If all that checks out, then refer to the online docs for FireDAC.  Somewhere you have a config problem - you just need to find it.

Comment: Right, I had a config problem. I have noticed  that the gds32.dll library in my SysWOW64 directory was dated 2001 and weighed 368 KB. So I replaced it by the gds32.dll in Interbase 2017 and everything went smoothly. I guess that the faulty library was put in there by the Interbase 6.5 installer that came with the old Delphi 7. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.  The D7 install of IB 6.5 sounds like the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I actually Deleted EMPLOYEE db in Inter base because I couldn't see the tables then I had to look all over the Internet for EMPLOYEE.gdb ,But I Solved this Issue by Just downloading Interbase To Go and then extracted the files in My inter base folder then extracted all windows_togo files and There I got EMPLOYEE.gdb .If you also face this Issuse you can also solve it by just downloading fire base (checkbox GDS32.dll while installation) in firebase folder you can Get EMPLOYEE.fdb (just change the extension to .gdb) and then copy paste that EMPLOYEE.gdb file to Your Interbase database folder in documents.